# Iterate by forEach loop in vanillaJS do not work for keyup event, but works fine for click event

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, foreach

I'm emitting by socket.IO poke-message to the user and on below code I achieved only (`onclick` parts) and it worked as it should but doesn't have idea what's wrong on keyup part... Also, tried on keydown event but didn't work. I don't want to do it by passing function declaration to the event as arg, but like anonymous function and better understand what's going on behind a scene. I'll appreciate any help or tip.

```
["keyup", "click"].forEach(
  (evt) =>
    document
      .getElementById(eachUser.buttonElement)
      .addEventListener(evt, () => {
        if ((evt === "keyup" && evt.keyCode === 13) || evt === "click") {
          const pokeMessage = document.getElementById(eachUser.inputElement)
            .value;
          private_socket.emit("poke message", {
            username: user.name,
            sessionID: user.sessionID,
            pokeMessage: pokeMessage,
          });
          pokeUser.parentNode.removeChild(pokeUser);
        } else {
          return;
        }
      }),
  false
);
```

Comment: `evt` is a string.  As such, `evt.keyCode` isn't a thing.

Comment: `.addEventListener(evt, () => {` should be `.addEventListener(evt, event => {` and then use the real `event` for your logic

Comment: @Taplar Sorry, but isn't that evt already treated as a event ? What do you mean real 'event' I'm lil bit confused

Comment: So look at where your `evt` is coming from.  It originates from the `forEach()`, as the value being passed into that callback.  You then use it as the first argument of the `addEventListener` method, which the first argument to that method is expected to be a string saying what events to bind to.

Comment: @Taplar Appreciate feedback "which the first argument to that method is expected to be a string saying what events to bind to."
Yeah... and it is bindend 'click' as a string right and 'keyup' can not be a string but it is passed like it? so i need to pass keyup as a object hardcoded to my list ?

Comment: No dude, read my second comment....  You literally just need to accept the event argument on the event handler method arguments and use it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you confused the `evt` variable coming from your `forEach` loop with the Event object that your code got as an argument, but didn't take.

In your code, `evt` is the name of the event for which the currently called listener was added (either `"keyup"` or `"click"`).

When you evaluate `evt.keyCode`, it returns `undefined` (neither of the event name strings have `keyCode` property), and your code stops working.

You probably wanted to access the `keyCode` property of the current event instead, which you can access as a parameter in the event listener:

```js
["keyup", "click"].forEach(
  (eventName) =>
// ^^^^^^^^^--- Renamed for clarity
    document
      .getElementById(eachUser.buttonElement)
      .addEventListener(eventName, eventObj => {
                          // ^^^^^^^^--- take argument (and name it whatever you want)
        if ((eventName === "keyup" && eventObj.keyCode === 13) || eventName === "click") {
          const pokeMessage = document.getElementById(eachUser.inputElement)
            .value;
          private_socket.emit("poke message", {
            username: user.name,
            sessionID: user.sessionID,
            pokeMessage: pokeMessage,
          });
          pokeUser.parentNode.removeChild(pokeUser);
        } else {
          return;
        }
      }),
  false
);
```